# Having problem to display Traceid and Spanid in JSON format using Log4J2 in Spring Boot project

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, log4j2, spring-cloud-sleuth

Is it possible to display the logs with JSON format and also display traceid and spanid in it by using Spring Sleuth. Please suggest the way to do this.

I have searched in google, YouTube and Github. I did not get the example in this combination. Please suggest the way or share links which is having this implementation.

Comment: check `net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder`, it does the same job.